# How take decimal symbol (string/char) in current region?

Tags: c#, uwp, globalization

I try find this in `Windows.Globalization`, but didn't find.

Is it possible to get it or not? If not? Are there alternative ways of formatting in different regions?

Example: `Convert.ToDouble("0" + Decimal_Symbol.ToString() + "0001")`;

Comment: A C# program can use System.Globalization.CultureInfo.  And Double.ToString() formats according to the user's current culture so you don't have to do anything special.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

char regionSymbol = (1.1).ToString()[1];

Answer (score 2):

It's in `System.Globalization`, not `Windows.Globalization`:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator
```

Answer (score 0):

you will find above an example of how to use the french culture, after according to your need you can change the culture.

```
        decimal decimalNumber = 1000.1m;
        var culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-fr");
        Console.WriteLine(decimalNumber.ToString(culture));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use **[CultureInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?view=netframework-4.7.2)**, and the **ToString** overload that asks [number formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings).
In this example, **N4** is a number displayed with 4 decimals:

```
var MyNumber = 123.4567m;
var MyCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("pt-BR");  // en-US  fr-FR

var Result = MyNumber.ToString("N4", MyCulture);
```